# how the same Instance work on different method on another class in java

Tags: java, object, thread-safety

Same instance is used in multiple method based on the argument providing. can we consider thread safety here.
Let's assume that we've 2 class,
**Class Main &
Class demo**.

```
Class Demo {
   returnType methodExample(args...) {
      //based on the argument provide it returns
      return something
   }
}

Class Main {
   Demo demo = new Demo();

   returnType method1() {
      value = demo.methodExample(args);
   }
   
   returnType method2() {
      value = demo.methodExample(args);
   }
}
```

will it share same ***Demo*** Instance. And what of both method works asynchronously.
please also describe the case in Spring Injecting by @AutoWired annotation

Apologies for typos or other mistakes.

Comment: What are you asking?

Comment: Your example is not giving complete picture here. What is args? Is it primitive or another class? You are invoking methods on Demo instance itself so it will obviously be same. Please be clear

Comment: Yes argument type is String. So based on the argument it returns the result but what if both the method that invokes the same instance. Like the output for method1() will go to method2() when this methods are called on same time.

Answer (score 1):

yes it will share same Demo instance. but the calculations are performed under method methodExample() is based on what value you are passed on parameters.
for using @autowire first you have to use @component annotation on Demo Class.

```
@Component
Class Demo {
   returnType methodExample(args...) {
      //based on the argument provide it returns
        return something
   }
}
Class Main {
   @Autowired
   Demo demo;

   returnType method1() {
      value = demo.methodExample(args);
   }

   returnType method2() {
      value = demo.methodExample(args);
   }
}
```